# Image rotation through entire directory?

Tags: python, windows, image, rotation

I need to rotate images in a directory by , 90, 180, 270 degrees. I have written code to singular image and now need to do it through the entire directory. This is in python and on Windows

```
import os
import glob
from PIL import Image
os.chdir("./")
for file in glob.glob("*.jpg"):
    image.rotate(file,90)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to open the file before rotate.

```
import os
import glob
from PIL import Image
os.chdir("./")
for file in glob.glob("*.jpg"):
    src_im = Image.open(file)
    src_im .rotate(90)
```

Comment: Thanks, however, when I run this it doesn't do anything. Would I need to add a save function to this for it to save in the directory after it rotates the image?

Comment: I am able to save the image, however it overwrites the original, I would like to be able to save the rotated image as a new image with this. Could you possibly help with that? @milanbalazs

Comment: You need to use a different path/name for saving rotated images. If you want to use eg. a suffix for saving you can try this: `src_im.save(file.replace(".jpg", "_rotated.jpg"))` In this case the name of files will be save with `_rotated` suffix. Please vote if my answer or our discussion helped you.

Comment: every time I run this code it continues to just copy the file and add the "_rotated.jpg" and not actually rotate the image.